# Drupal 7 - node Form template is not used

Tags: php, forms, templates, drupal, drupal-7

I have a Problem with one node type and it's form. I want to alter it with an template file. I already did this with another node type on my drupal site and this worked, but it doesn't work for this second type.

So (as I did for the other node type) I placed this hook in my module:

```
function MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'FORM_ID' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
          'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'TYPE-node-form',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE'),
    ),

  );
}
```

And also declared this function (in my module):

```
function template_preprocess_TYPE_node_form(&$variables) {
   /* Some hide(elements) and stuff */
}
```

And of course, I created the file TYPE-node-form.tpl.php in the module directory

```
/* Something */
TEST
    <?php if($form): ?>
      <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
/* Something more */
```

But it does not load this template ( I cannot see TEST and the other things). Also after multiply times of clearing cache and refreshing.

With DisplaySuite I was able to set a template in the backend (Administration » Structure » Content types » TYPE » Manage fields). But I want to have my own template file (and also not located in the sites/all/modules/ds/layout/.. folder). Deactivating DisplaySuite also does not do the trick. 
I also looked tried to place the `MY_THEME_theme()` code into the template.php file of the administrator theme, but it also did not work.

Any suggestions? What can I do? Is there a way to find out which template is used or where it is overwritten? I have read that Themes overwrite modules templates declaration?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using D7, `hook_theme` implementations do not have `'arguments'` key, but `'variables'`.

Also in this case **remove** the `'arguments'` or `'variables'` key in order for the `'render element'` to work. Hope this helps.

Final code:

```
function MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return array(
     'FORM_ID' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'TYPE-node-form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE'),
     ),
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have removed that element but it is still not working.

Comment: Perhaps there's something else overriding your theme/template. Here's a sample of the code I've tested:
``function MY_MODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'article_node_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'article-node-form',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE')
    )
  );
}`` with a ``article-node-form.tpl.php`` file in the root of **MY_MODULE** module.

Comment: But I do not find where it is overridden. Where do I have to look? front-end and back-end theme template.php files? Is there an easier way to find out which template is actually used?

Comment: And why does also the `function template_preprocess_TYPE_node_form(&$variables)`
 not work?

Comment: Thanks @Claudiu Chirilov , it works. There was a very bad mistake included which I don't want to share here. ;) The template works, but still, the preprocess hook does not work. Any suggestions for that?